# What to do for missing data in time series

Tags: time-series, missing-data

If a time series has several runs of missing data is it best to impute the mean of the previous observations?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Please give more information about the purpose of your analysis.

Comment: Please take the time to explain more about your problem. "Several" and "best" are really vague concepts.

Comment: I suggest you this simply python implementation with KalmanFilter for a clever data imputation in timeseries  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630858/10375049

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest looking into multiple imputation algorithms. Gary King has produced a package for R called [Amelia](http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia) that does very sophisticated multiple imputation and can handle time series quite well. Amelia treats all of the data as multivariate normal and performs multiple random draws from that distribution until the draws converge on the final imputed value. But there are a number of customization features that you can incorporate so that you can sculpt Amelia runs to your particular problem, such as including lags, leads, and polynomial expressions.

Comment: Is imputing the mean still a valid option?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to set the missing values equal to the mean of the preceding values. This might be fine if your data are missing completely at random and normally-distributed around a mean consistent throughout the time series, and not sensitive to fluctuations in explanatory variables.

Comment: @phil12: I'd say probably not. You really need to answer Rob Hyndman's question to your original posting. How much data do you have, how much is missing, what are you doing with it? There's no answer without knowing.

Comment: Imputing the mean is almost certainly not a valid option for a realistic time series.  To see why, take a good time series like GDP, the AirPassengers set built into R, or anything you have to hand, delete a few values at random and replace them with the mean, plot the result and see how bad it looks.

Comment: In my opinion the best solution is to fill missing values with your  own proposed model (the model that you want to use for the time series) as prediction and re-estimate until it converges. It is slow but not an ad-hoc imputation solution. It is an EM procedure.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc This is a more restrictive alternative than Gary King's recommendation in the AMELIA II documentation, in which he writes that using *all available data*, including data not used in your particular model, to construct imputed data sets is preferred and produces better results.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good application for [the EM algorithm of Shumway and Stoffer](https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/dss_files/em.pdf).

First you need to specify your arima model, then you can use the Kalman Filter because is can handle missing values (see [the Durbin and Koopman textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019964117X)).

For starting parameter values you can compute the expected value of the missing values, then you maximize over the parameters given the missing values and you iterate.

This is very well explained in [http://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-Its-Applications-Statistics/dp/144197864X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144197864X) page 344 in the State-Space model chapter.

I hope it helps!